# Django: Saving multiple ManyToMany fields within a transaction

Tags: python, django, model, manytomanyfield

this is the representation of my models:

```
class B(models.Model):
   """I'm a dummy model, so doesn't pay atention of what I do"""
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class A(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   many_b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
```

Now, suppose I have a list of `B` objects. And a single `A` object that will be related to that `B`s. Something like this:

```
a = A.objects.get(id=1)
list_of_b = [B<name='B1'>,B<name='B2'>,B<name='B3'>,]
```

The way I relate them now is this:

```
for b_object in list_of_b:
   a.many_b.add(b_object)
```

Is there any way to add all the B objects in a single transaction? Maybe in a single method, like:

```
a.many_b.addList(b) #This doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields):

```
>>> john = Author.objects.create(name="John")
>>> paul = Author.objects.create(name="Paul")
>>> george = Author.objects.create(name="George")
>>> ringo = Author.objects.create(name="Ringo")
>>> entry.authors.add(john, paul, george, ringo)
```

So if you have a list, use argument expansion:

```
a.many_b.add(*list_of_b)
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the argument expansion. If the whole view is within a transaction is this call executed within that transaction?

Comment: @santiagobasulto Yes, the transaction middleware should put all writes in one transaction, including this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want is a kind of bulk insert right?

As far as I know this is just available in the Django TRUNK not in 1.3!

check it out some tutorial:
http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/09/20/bulk-inserts-django/

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I'll take a look. Thank you!